# How to access parent function from imported element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, ecmascript-6

I have a listview in `index.js` my react native project like below.

```
import ResultRow from './resultRow'

class ResultList extends Component {
    constructor() {

    }

    updateDate(){
        //Some operation
    }

    onPressRow() {
        try {
          console.log("Selected!");

        //Some operation

          this.updateDate(); // Got undefined is not a function

        } catch (error) {      
          console.error(error);
        }
    }

    renderRow(rowData) {
        return (
          <ResultRow
          onPress={this.onPressRow}
            {...rowData} />
        )
      }

    render() {
      return (
              <ListView
                style={[styles.container, { padding: 10, backgroundColor: '#ddd' }]}
                dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
                renderRow={this.renderRow.bind(this)} />
            );
    }

}
```

And bind list items using this template in `resultRow.js` file like below.

```
import React from 'react';
import { TouchableHighlight, StyleSheet, Image,View } from 'react-native';

const ResultRow = (props) => (
  <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => props.onPress()}>
    <View>
      <Text>My Row</Text>       
    </View>
  </TouchableHighlight >
);

export default ResultRow;
```

If I select a row from list view `onPress` event called. And `onPressRow` function is executed. from `onPressRow` function I called another function which is defined in same class named "`updateDate`". I call like this `this.updateDate();` But got `undefined is not a function error`.

What I am doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bind the function or use arrow functions! `this.onPressRow = this.onPressRow.bind(this);` in constructor.

Comment: @AndrewLi thanks. fixed now :)

Answer (score 1):

You need to `bind` the function as `this` doesn't refer to the appropriate context in your code. You can make use of arrow function

```
onPressRow = () => {
        try {
          console.log("Selected!");

        //Some operation

          this.updateDate(); 

        } catch (error) {      
          console.error(error);
        }
   }
```

The other way to bind you function is to set the binding in the constructor

```
constructor() {
   super();
   this.onPressRow = this.onPressRow.bind(this);
}
```

In fact you will need to `bind` any function that will make use of `this` to refer to the `context` of your react class.

Comment: Your example isn't valid ECMAScript 6. It would be useful to others if you explained what to do in order to gets this (experimental) feature to work.